# Have DrawingImage inherit color from containing Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have a few buttons that have a common style. This style has a `ContentPresenter`, which is filled with a `DrawingImage` in the button declaration.

This works just fine when the `DrawingImage` uses a predefined brush. However I would very much like my `DrawingImage` to use the Foreground color that is used in the style, or on the button if it is overridden there.

How can I accomplish this?

My current style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DrawingImage x:Key="SomeIcon">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="PATH" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="OTHER_PATH" />
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>

    <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton">
        <!-- I want this icon to be Blue as inherited from the style. -->
        <Image Source="{StaticResource SomeIcon}"/>
    </Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton" Foreground="Red">
        <!-- I want this icon be Red as overriden by the button -->
        <Image Source="{StaticResource SomeIcon}"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I only want pure XAML answers. Other XAML routes towards the same goal are also appreciated, for instance using `Path` instead of `DrawingImage`.

Comment: "using Path instead of DrawingImage" is the way to go. Did you try anything in that direction?

Comment: @Clemens I did try, but didn't have any luck with it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the icon resource as a Geometry, and have a Button Style with a Path like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="SomeIcon">M0,20 L20,0 40,20 20,40Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="PathButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                          Data="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          Stretch="None"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource PathButtonStyle}" 
            Content="{StaticResource SomeIcon}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can see you're using only one path (one `Geometry` element). What about when you have multiple paths like in my example?

Comment: Use a GeometryGroup for example (which also is a Geometry). Note also that the path markup syntax allows to create multiple figure. There is only a need for multiple Paths when you have different strokes or fills, which apparently you don't want.

Comment: There's some kind of strange duplication going on when I modified my code to follow your example (and using a `GeometryGroup` with several `Geometry` inside). Icon from my example to the left, and icon from your example with default color and overriden color to the center and right: http://i.imgur.com/IZR74kp.png If I type an invalid value into the `Foreground` property on the button, there is no duplication.

Comment: If you look at the image I linked to in that comment you'll see that the two rightmost icons are thicker than the one on the left. You'll also see that the red one seems more outlined, as it still has some white in the center.

Comment: The two icons on the right seem to have Stroke and Fill set, while the one on the left only has a Fill. You may vary the Path's StrokeThickness or don't set a Stroke at all.

Comment: Adding `StrokeThickness="0"`seems to have solved it. Thanks :)

Comment: Or just remove `Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"`.